# Python для задач data mining

Tags: c++, python, erlang, big-data

Скажите пожалуйста, почему для задач data mining'a очень часто используют питон?

Чем в данном случае будет лучше например того же Erlang'a или C++?

Comment: Никогда не понимал что значит слово data-mining. Это какой-то эвфемизм для длинного SQL запроса к очередной БД или так говорят когда кого-то приспичит зачем-то параллельно сортировать очердную терабайтную таблицу с помощью всей окружающей его сети?

Comment: @igumnov, ну вы видимо просто никогда не работали с аналитикой. Нет, это не эвфемизм для выборки из баз данных, оно вообще с БД напрямую не связанно. Data Mining - это прогнозирование, и анализ различными программными алгоритмами. Самый бытовой пример - есть у нас данные о ценах нефти, продовольствия, драгметалов распределенных по различным странам, и датам. И вот мы берем их, выводим прогноз роста различных национальных валют. )

Answer (score 6):

Быстротой разработки. На С++ вы можете 3 недели писать то, что написали на Python за 3 дня.

Обычно прототип пишется на Python, а чтобы увеличить производительность, переписывают на Си, например.

Answer (score 1):

Тем что под Python написано огромное множество библиотек для целей Data Mining и Вам не придется изобретать велосипед, а будет возможность использовать все написанное до Вас.